# Parse KML file with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, google-maps, simplexml, kml

Is there a way to parse google maps *.kml file with simple_xml_load_file("*.kml") ?

I need to save in my database name and coordinates of each polygons registered in my KML file.
On my PHP script, simple_xml_load_file("*.kml") return false, so I can't read it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <Document>
        <Schema>
        ...
        </Schema>
        <Style id="FEATURES">
        ...
        </Style>
        <Folder>
            <Placemark>
                <name>
                    name
                </name>
                <Polygon>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            coordinates
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                ...
            </Placemark>
        </Folder>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

I need "name" and "coordinates" values for each "Placemark".

Comment: Hello newbie, you should include some example nodes from your .kml. Expected results .. etc and so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Tells PHP that this is a document encoded in UTF-8, but your error says it is not encoded as UTF-8. Is this a doc you created with a text editor? If so, you can usually use your editor to save it out in UTF-8. Or you can probably use PHP to detect the encoding and change that first line.

Comment: Right thanks. File that i'm trying to upload was not save in UTF-8. I've just re-save it in a text-editor, and it's works fine ! Is there a way to force UTF-8 encodage of a file upload ?

Comment: Depends on your text editor, I'd look it up in the settings. Or you can write a script that would read an input file and produce an output file that is UTF-8 encoded. PHP has the following function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php
Or you find out what the encoding is and use that in the XML header instead of UTF-8

Comment: It's what I've done. First, I convert my file to string with $str = file_gets_content($file) and I load it with simplexml_laod_string(utf8_encode($str)); .. and it's works :) !

Answer (score 5):

```
The xml structure is exactly that xml you sent:

For example:

<Document>
<Placemark>
      <name>356HH</name>
      <description>
</description>
      <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>some cordinates here</coordinates></LinearRing></innerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
  <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle>  <PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
</document>
```

And it's my php code:

```
<?php

$completeurl = "2.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($completeurl);

$placemarks = $xml->Document->Placemark;
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","j3");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 $query = '';
 $run='';
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($placemarks); $i++) {
    $coordinates = $placemarks[$i]->name;
     $cor_d  =  explode(' ', $placemarks[$i]->Polygon->outerBoundaryIs->LinearRing->coordinates);
     $qtmp=array();
     foreach($cor_d as $value){
          $tmp = explode(',',$value);
          $ttmp=$tmp[1];
          $tmp[1]=$tmp[0];
          $tmp[0]=$ttmp; 
          $qtmp[]= '(' . $tmp[0] . ',' .$tmp[1].')';
     }

    $cor_d = json_encode($qtmp);
    $query .='\''.$coordinates.'\', \''.$cor_d.'\'';
    $run .="INSERT INTO jos_rpl_addon_zipinfo (name, boundary) VALUES (".$query." );";

    //echo $run;
    //break;
}
mysqli_query($con,$run);
//echo $run;

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is not exactly the same but is it similar. You save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

If the XML strucutre is as what you have posted, you can try :-

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(...);
$childs = $xml->Document->Folder->children();
foreach ($childs as $child)
{
    // child object is same as -> Placemark

}
```

Example :-

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [name] => 
                    name

    [Polygon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [LinearRing] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [coordinates] => 
                            coordinates

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I tried to do this but `$xml = simplexml_load_file(...);` return false. So, I can't get $xml->***.

Comment: What sort of error you gotten? ANd `*.xml` is a invalid syntax (you must specifically load one XML and one time)

Comment: "*.kml" is only for not specify the name of my file here.  simple_xml_load_file(my_file) returns a false boolean with the error "Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xE8 0x72 0x65 0x73 ""

Comment: There are <![CDATA[xxxx]]> in my KML file. It's maybe this ?

Comment: Unlikely, do you have tidy module installed ? If so, take a look here :- http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Comment: KML isn't recognized by tidy. I think my KML file has a problem because it work's with another more simple.

Comment: I mean you set the input source as XML, and set output source as XML, write to a new XML, then parse against the new XML?

Comment: I have a HTML Form with a `<input type="file">` who upload my KML file, I juste want to parse it for insert into my database the coordinates and the name of each polygons saved in this file.

Comment: Is not easy answer, an user can provide a malform XML or include some UTF characters. Take a look on what Tidy can do (repair feature)

Comment: Tried this but iteration seems to stop after reading the first child of the XML structure. :/