# Import KML into postgis database using PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, postgis

How can I import a KML file inside a postgis database?

I need to import the KML file and insert it into a specific column which has a type of polygon.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse KML file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342337/parse-kml-file-with-php)

Comment: But there is no correct accepted answer there.. He turned out to have an issue with encoding

Comment: You can feed some elements to [ST_GeomFromKML](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromKML.html) from SQL

Comment: @MikeT your solution works.. could you add an answer so I can accept it? maybe with an example.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an SQL interface, you can try feeding the text for fragments of the KML file with [ST_GeomFromKML](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromKML.html).

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromKML('
<Polygon>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
            -122.377830,37.830445,0
            -122.377576,37.830631,0
            -122.377840,37.830642,0
            -122.377830,37.830445,0
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a fully automated import use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html):

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='database_geo' host='localhost' port='5432' user='xxx password='xxx'" KML_Samples.kml
```